# Kubernetes dashboard not accessible after change service to node port

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-service, kubernetes-dashboard

We have multi-node cluster setup, now try to install dashboard.

I ran command `kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/dashboard/v2.4.0/aio/deploy/recommended.yaml`  and it deploy all resource.

I check the service is created.

```
# kubectl get services -n kubernetes-dashboard
NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.103.75.109    <none>        8000/TCP   4m53s
kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.106.194.108   <none>        443/TCP    4m53s
```

Then try to access the service url.

```
# curl https://10.106.194.108 -k
<!--
Copyright 2017 The Kubernetes Authors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
--><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kubernetes Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/kubernetes-logo.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>body,html{height:100%;margin:0;}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa0538c9a91ebbb04705.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa0538c9a91ebbb04705.css"></noscript></head>

<body>
  <kd-root></kd-root>
<script src="runtime.1a20bc8321eb559541a1.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.2565916e4afd13edaa84.js" defer></sc
  creationTimestamp: "2021-11-09T21:20:14Z"
ript><script src="scripts.f76573725d49abb057d3.js" defer></script><script src="en.main.7f7baee1f12d075d7cb9.js" defer></script>


</body></html>
```

Then I follow the steps to convert `ClusterIP` to `NodePort`,

Service before conversion.

```
# kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe service kubernetes-dashboard
Name:              kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:         kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:            k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:              ClusterIP
IP Family Policy:  SingleStack
IP Families:       IPv4
IP:                10.106.194.108
IPs:               10.106.194.108
Port:              <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:        8443/TCP
Endpoints:         192.168.211.130:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

Service after edit using `kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard edit service kubernetes-dashboard` command.

```
# kubectl -n kubernetes-dashboard describe service kubernetes-dashboard
Name:                     kubernetes-dashboard
Namespace:                kubernetes-dashboard
Labels:                   k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Annotations:              <none>
Selector:                 k8s-app=kubernetes-dashboard
Type:                     NodePort
IP Family Policy:         SingleStack
IP Families:              IPv4
IP:                       10.106.194.108
IPs:                      10.106.194.108
Port:                     <unset>  443/TCP
TargetPort:               8443/TCP
NodePort:                 <unset>  32358/TCP
Endpoints:                192.168.211.130:8443
Session Affinity:         None
External Traffic Policy:  Cluster
Events:                   <none>
```

then `curl https://10.106.194.108:32358 -k` never return data :(.

I check the pod IP, and its working.

```
# curl https://192.168.211.130:8443 -k
<!--
Copyright 2017 The Kubernetes Authors.

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
You may obtain a copy of the License at

    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
limitations under the License.
--><!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en"><head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Kubernetes Dashboard</title>
  <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/images/kubernetes-logo.png">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<style>body,html{height:100%;margin:0;}</style><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa0538c9a91ebbb04705.css" media="print" onload="this.media='all'"><noscript><link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.aa0538c9a91ebbb04705.css"></noscript></head>

<body>
  <kd-root></kd-root>
<script src="runtime.1a20bc8321eb559541a1.js" defer></script><script src="polyfills.2565916e4afd13edaa84.js" defer></script><script src="scripts.f76573725d49abb057d3.js" defer></script><script src="en.main.7f7baee1f12d075d7cb9.js" defer></script>


</body></html>
```

How to check why its not working after changing to `NodePort` ?

Comment: run `kubectl get node -o wide` this would give the IP of the node. Use that IP with the port of the nodePort service to curl....

Answer (score 1):

k8s nodeport service works like this :

which means your valid endpoint would be

```
http://{NODE_IP}:{PORT}
```

[image]